# How to specify the depth of a regression tree in matlab?

Tags: matlab, classification, decision-tree

I am using the regression tree (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/classregtree.html) to classify some data. My data has 9 features, however the regression tree will give me a decision tree only based on the best two features that split the classes. I want to see more features being used in the classification. I've read the documentation but found nothing. Can you point me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to pruning, which is `on` by default. Try setting it to `off`:

```
t = classregtree(X, y, 'prune','off')
```

Comment: Then you should probably post a reproducible example for us to try.

Comment: you mean 30x9 matrix? that is tiny IMO.

Comment: Then you can use this git repo to test the result. look inside the letterClassifier.m file there is a function called alternativeclassifier uses the regression tree to classify them.

Comment: can you try `minparent=2` and `mergeleaves=off` (at the moment I don't have access to my machine)